Adjust yaml.Dumper to export dataclasses and their docstrings
I would like to export dataclass objects including their docstrings (as # commented description above) to yaml.
So far I've figured out that I need a custom dumper or adjust the current one.
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class foo:
"""This would be a nice to have docstring but can be joined"""

   bar: int = 1
   """This is bar"""

# Export

import yaml
class SomeDumper(yaml.Dumper):
   """What is needed here?"""

yaml.dump(foo, "foo.yaml", dumper=SomeDumper)

Expected output:
# -----
# This would be a nice to have docstring but can be joined
# -----

# This is bar
bar : 1

How do I need to adjust the Dumper to keep the docstrings like shown above?
For simplicity assume that I have the docstrings, and I only care on how to adjust the dumper, the docstrings I can extract with this gist

You want comments in your output, and PyYAML doesn't support that. Of course you can rewrite the representer, emitter, etc, but I think you should consider upgrading to ruamel.yaml which not only can preserve comments (or attach them to data to be dumped), but also supports YAML 1.2. PyYAML only supports a subset of YAML 1.1, outdated in 2009, another reason to consider upgrading to something better.

Thank you Anthon, I hoped I could go with a few lines of adjusting the string representation of a node vs. adding another dependency. I already have a dumper from another module I would like to use and adjust further to keep other things aligned.

First of all it is very easy to extract doctring from the class.
Then, regarding to arguments comments or argumens docstrings you will either need to find good library that do this for you (such libraries most probably created on top of code inspection functionality). Or what is much easier is to start with using typing "Annotated" for commenting arguments. Will this solution work for you?
Solution 1:
Specify arguments docs in the Annotated typing hints.
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import get_type_hints, Annotated, get_args


@dataclass
class Foo:
    """This would be a nice to have docstring but can be joined"""

    bar: Annotated[int, "This is bar"] = 1
    msg: Annotated[int, "This is msg"] = 1

print (foo.__doc__)

for arg, _type in Foo.__annotations__.items():
    arg_comment = get_args(_type)[1]
    print(f"{arg} -- {arg_comment}")

Solution 2:
Specify arguments in the docstring. Then you can use libraries for automatic docs generation to parse definition of each of the arguments:
import docstring_parser
from typing import Optional

class Docstring:

    def __init__(self, doc: str):
        self._docstring = docstring_parser.parse(doc)
        self.params_docs = {param_doc.arg_name: param_doc for param_doc in self._docstring.params}
        self.short_description = self._docstring.short_description
        self.long_description = self._docstring.long_description

    def get_description(self) -> Optional[str]:
        blank_line = self._docstring.blank_after_short_description and '\n' or ''
        long_description = self.long_description and f'\n{blank_line}{self.long_description}' or ''
        return self.short_description and self.short_description + long_description

    def get_argument_description(self, argument_name: str) -> str:
        param_doc = self.params_docs.get(argument_name)
        description = param_doc.description if param_doc is not None else ''

        return description

@dataclass
class Foo:
    """This would be a nice to have docstring but can be joined

    :param bar: description 1
    :param msg: description 1

    """

    bar: int = 1
    msg: int = 1
    


docstring = Docstring(Foo.__doc__)

print(docstring.get_description())


for arg, _type in Foo.__annotations__.items():
    arg_comment = docstring.get_argument_description('bar')
    print(f"{arg} -- {arg_comment}")

    

How to add comments to YAML representaion
Now to second part of your question. I think that the easiest way would be to reuse ruamel-yaml library. It doesn't have an extensively described docs, but here is an example on how you can use it to add comments to your YAML:
from dataclasses import dataclass, asdict

from typing import List, Dict

import io
import sys 

from ruamel.yaml import YAML

@dataclass
class Foo:
    """ This is a Foo class representation"""

    bar: int = 1
    msg: int = 1
    flag: int = 1
    name: int = 1


def dump_foo_to_string(foo: Foo) -> str:
    """ dump Foo into YAML string """
    buf = io.StringIO()
    yaml.dump(asdict(foo), buf)
    yaml_str = buf.getvalue()    
    return yaml_str


# list of foo attributes
foo_attr: List[str] = Foo.__annotations__.keys()

# main Foo docstring
class_documentation = Foo.__doc__

attr_comments:Dict[str,str] = {'bar': 'a bar comment',
                               'msg': 'a msg comment'}



# we need to convert dataclass to dictionary
# and then we can add comments to our yaml class representation
foo_yaml_str = dum_foo_to_string(Foo())


# load yaml from string
yaml = YAML(typ='rt')
data = yaml.load(foo_yaml_str)


# add starting comment
data.yaml_set_start_comment(class_documentation)

# add EOL comment
data.yaml_add_eol_comment("name attr comment", key = 'name')

# add comments to all other attributes
for key in foo_attr:
    if key not in attr_comments:
        continue
    comment_txt = attr_comments[key]
    # data.yaml_add_eol_comment(comment_txt, key = key)
    data.yaml_set_comment_before_after_key(key, comment_txt)

yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)

The output of this codeblock is:
#  This is a Foo class representation
# a bar comment
bar: 1
# a msg comment
msg: 1
flag: 1
name: 1  # name attr comment


Thank you. Getting the docstrings is not the problem just the yaml export. I know about, ruamel.yaml but would like to avoid the extra dependency, thinking I just need to adjust the string value in the node when I dump it with documentation.

sry, it wasn't clear for your initial question. However I've checked ruamel.yaml and it doesn't lead to any extra dependencies except package itself. Basically upi can regard it as extension to yaml package
